# Is the Kalman Filter computationally optimal for Kalman filtering?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, estimation-theory, stochastic-filtering, hidden-markov-models

Kalman filtering is known to be a recursive process that minimizes mean square error in linear problems.

My question is: has anybody shown that this algorithm is computationally optimal, i.e. that you cannot obtain a MMSE estimator in linear problems with a different, computationally more inexpensive set of steps?

The background for this question is a comparison of Neural Networks vs. Kalman Filters. Any paper that proves/shows a model-trained Neural Network cannot replicate model-specific Kalman filtering more efficiently would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I should have clarified that I mean computationally optimal in the exploitation (on-line) phase.

Training a Neural Network is computationally expensive, but once you have frontloaded such cost, once you're doing online estimation (once you start receiving the noisy samples), I'm not sure the cost wouldn't be lower.